# Vim: Function to open current file in a default vim

Tags: vim

I know you can do the following to get a default vim.

```
:!vim -u NONE %:p
```

I would like to do the above command but stay on the line number I was on before, in my custom vim, while exiting out of my old custom vim session. Is this possible?

*EDITs*:
The following shows that you can use `line(".")` from your current vim session:
[In Vim, is there a way to copy the current line number into a buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295321/in-vim-is-there-a-way-to-copy-the-current-line-number-into-a-buffer)

then you can do something like

```
:!vim -u NONE +line(".") %:p
```

Note: Something is still wrong in the above. Also the old vim session keeps running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you need do this, but this could be one way:

in your "full-featured" vim:

```
:let n=line('.')|let p=expand('%:p')|bd|exec '!vim -u NONE +'. n .' '. p
```

this will do what you want, and from your customized vim close the current file (buffer). However, the two vims are nested.

Comment: When I'm editing really large files some plugins suck and cause lag, and just get in the way of simple edits. Is there a possible way to get out of the nested vims and just have one?

Comment: Also do you know the correct way to map something like that? 
  
`map <silent> <D-1> :let n=line('.')|let p=expand('%:p')|bd|exec '!vim -u NONE +'. n .' '. p<cr>`

Comment: I've been using the LargeFile plugin, but sometimes one of my other plugins which does a screen redraw causes a lot of lag so I just want to make a few changes using the default vim.

Comment: Kent, know how I could fix that mapping?

Answer (score 2):

When you have a problem with large files bogging down Vim so much to hinder editing, launching a completely new one is a bit harsh. Rather, check whether the [LargeFile - Edit large files quickly](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506) plugin already helps.

If that isn't sufficient, I'd investigate the `:autocmd`s (especially on `CursorMoved[I]`), and `:syntax off`, and then make a custom command `:HandleLargeFile` to turn off those options and plugins.